# SQL - Properties Structure

Tags: sql

What is the best way to setup this table structure.

I have 3 tables, one table we'll call fruit and the other two tables are properties of that fruit so fruit_detailed and fruit_basic.

### fruit

id | isDetailed

### fruit_detailed

id | price | color | source | weight | fruitid?

### fruit_basic

id | value | fruitid?

So what I want to do is have a property in fruit called isDetailed and if true, fill the fruit_detailed table with properties like color, weight, source, etc (multiple column). If its false then store in fruit_basic table with properties written in a single row.

Storage sounds quite basic but if I want to select a fruit and get its properties, how can I determine which table to join? I could use and IF statement on the isDetailed property and then join like that but then you have two different types of properties coming back

How would you create the tables or do the join to get the properties? Am I missing something?

Comment: For one thing you need a fruit_Detailed_id field in the fruit table. This should be the primary key id of the fruit_detailed entry that corresponds to it.

fruit.isDetailed is probably not even necessary. If no fruit.fruit_detailed_id exists then the fruit has not been detailed.

Comment: if I didn't have the detailed information for a fruit, and I wanted to enter it into fruit_basic, how will the fruit table know that there's an entry in fruit_basic? So information about the fruit can be entered in detailed or in basic and not both

Comment: Fruit_basic also requires an id in the fruit table. \I agree with Joe Stefanelli though, a single table makes more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably model this like so:

```
CREATE TABLE Fruits (
    fruit_id    INT    NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Fruit PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (fruit_id)
)

CREATE TABLE Fruit_Details (
    fruit_id    INT               NOT NULL,
    price       MONEY             NOT NULL,
    color       VARCHAR(20)       NOT NULL,
    source      VARCHAR(20)       NOT NULL,
    weight      DECIMAL(10, 4)    NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Fruit_Detail PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (fruit_id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Fruit_Detail_Fruit FOREIGN KEY (fruit_id) REFERENCES Fruit (fruit_id)
)
```

I had to guess on appropriate data types for some of the columns. I'm also not sure exactly what the "value" column is in your `Fruit_Basic` table, so I've left that out for now.

Don't bother putting a bunch of IDs out there simply for the sake of having an ID column on every table. The Fruits->Fruit_Details relationship is a one-to-zero-or-one relationship. In other words, you can have at most one Fruit_Details row for each Fruits row. In some cases you might have no row in Fruit_Details for a particular row in Fruits.

When you're querying you can simply `OUTER JOIN` from the `Fruits` table to the `Fruit_Details` table. If you get back a `NULL` value for `Fruit_Details.fruit_id` then you know that the fruit doesn't have any details. You can always include the `Fruit_Details` columns, they'll just be `NULL` if the row doesn't exist. That way you can always have homogeneous resultsets. As you've discovered, otherwise you end up having to worry about different column lists coming back depending on the row in question, which will lead to tons of headaches.

If you want to include an "isDetailed" column then you can just use this:

```
CASE WHEN Fruit_Details.fruit_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS isDetailed
```

This approach also has an advantage over putting all of the columns in one table because it lowers the number of `NULL` columns in your database and depending on your data can substantially decrease storage requirements and improve performance.

Comment: hi tom, the "value" in the fruit_basic column is just a free text to describe the fruit anyway you want so its not structured as the detail version. The table setup you have is straight forward but I just want to introduce the fruit_basic table and then have the Fruits table know which table to join to. So it should know if its a detailed fruit or a basic one.

Comment: Aren't you going to need to know that before you query? I mean, it's not like you can ask for all fruit and have the resultset be a mix of two different column sets. I'd add the Fruit_Basic table (if the value isn't appropriate for all fruit) and then always join on both tables, returning all rows. The front end can then sort them out and handle each row appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I see no need to split the basic and detailed attributes out into separate tables. I think they can/should all be columns of the main fruit table.

Comment: Basically I just wanted to have a structured version of the details of a fruit and an unstructed version of the details. Using the fruits probably isn't the best example now that I think about it. A better example might be a persons address. You can fill in a structured address so house number, street name, zip, country etc. Or you can do an unstructured version so address line 1, address line 2, etc. So you fill in one or the other and somehow the main table knows which one it links too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would need to store a basic or detailed list of the fruit in different tables. You should just have 1 table and then leave some of the fields null if the information doesn't exist.

Assuming that value from fruit_basic is the same as price from fruit_detailed, you'd have something like this.

**fruit**

id | detail_id (fk to fruit_detailed table)

**fruit_details**

detail_id | price | color | source | weight

Comment: its a possible approach but I didn't want to introduce the null fields. If i dont know the fruit details, the basic version allows me to describe it. Of course you can just introduce a field in fruit_details called "description". But if the details have 20 columns, its a waste of space. I would like to know if the fruit is linked to a detailed version or a basic version.